# Plugin to show a widget hashtag as widget or shortcode?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, twitter

Is there a plugin that will show the results of a Twitter hashtag search either as a a widget or in a post/page via a shortcode? The shortcode is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you want. Shortcode that will output link to Twitter search for hashtag? Could you provide example link and desired shortcode format?

Answer (score 2):

There's [Tweet Blender](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet-blender/), seems pretty flexible and full of options:

> Provides several Twitter widgets: show
>   your own tweets, show tweets relevant
>   to post's tags, show tweets for
>   Twitter lists, show tweets for hashtags

[Twitter Hash Tag Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-hash-tag-widget/):

> A widget for displaying the most
>   recent twitter status updates for a
>   particular hash tag.

[Twitter Tracker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tracker/):

> A widget which allows you to specify
>   and display a Twitter search (or a
>   Twitter hashtag) in your sidebar.
>   Twitter searches are very flexible,
>   and you can display anything from
>   Hashtags to individual, or aggregated
>   Twitter streams.

Hope these work. To add shortcode support would be pretty easy for any of the developers of these plugins, so it would just be a matter of asking them to do so.

Comment: The Twitter Hash Tag Widget hasn't been updated in more than two years now. Probably better to use Tweet Blender or Twitter Tracker.

Comment: Don't they need to conform to Twitter API guidelines, showing tweets with a predefined design?

Answer (score 0):

You could use just the RSS widget and the hashtag feed. For example:

```
https://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23hashtag
```